# laravel ignore return redirect()

Tags: php, laravel

hi guys i'm trying to redirect user to bank but laravel is ignoring my return redirect

in here

```
public function checkout()
{
    
    $order = $this->makeOrder();

    $this->makePayment($order);

    $pal = resolve(zarinpal::class);

    $pal -> pay($order);

    $this->basket->clear();

    return $order;
}
```

i'm calling pay() in zarinpal class :

```
public function pay(Order $order)
{
    $this->redirectToBank($order);
}

private function redirectToBank($order)
{
    $zarinpal = zarinpal()
        ->amount($order->amount_rial)
        ->request()
        ->callback('http://lanjani/payment/zarinpal/callback')
        ->description($order->code)
        ->mobile($order->phone_number)
        ->send();

    if (!$zarinpal->success()){
        return $zarinpal->error()->message();
    }

    $authority=$zarinpal->authority();

    $input = [
        'authority' => $authority
    ];

    $orderItem = Order::find($order->id);

    $orderItem -> update($input);

    return redirect()->away('https://sandbox.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/'.$authority);

}
```

at the end of redirectToBank() user must redirect to bank but it is ignoring redirect and is returning $order in cheackout()

Comment: if you put `dd('here')` right before the redirect does it fire?

Comment: yes everything is ok

Comment: I don't know if I am right, but what happends when you return `$this->redirectToBank($order);` from the pay method and `$pal -> pay($order);` from the checkout method. I am pretty sure that redirect returns an object which needs to be returned form the method on the route.

Comment: yes the problem was if i wanted to redirect in my class that i'm calling in controller i have to return this exact method in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the redirect returns a redirect object. And this object needs to be returned from the method on the route. So you would return

```
$pal -> pay($order);
```

from the checkout method and

```
$this->redirectToBank($order);
```

from the pay method. This obviously does not really have the effect you want. So you will need to return the redirect url form the `redirectToBank` method and then clear the basket and then in the checkout method redirect away.

Answer (score -1):

You missed a return

```
public function pay(Order $order)
{
    return $this->redirectToBank($order);
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is not working too i'm so confused

Comment: Oh sorry I was a little confused about what was the first controller method you were calling. The redirect() method will only create an object that must be returned by the controller, you must pass that back up and return that. So adding in also `$redirect =  $pal -> pay($order);` and then `return $redirect` at the bottom

Comment: but checkout is returning $order how can i return $redirect

Comment: and checkout() is in another class that controller is using

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what is being called, but if you want to redirect upon calling a route, you'll need return a redirect object (created by calling `redirect()`) in the controller that is originally called.

Comment: It's returning an order right now because you have `return $order` in your controller, and it'll do that if that is the only return in your originally called controller